# I am having troubles with my play/pause button on my customised video

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video

```
Here is my html code:

<div id='media-controls'>
<button id='play-pause-button' class='play' title='play' onclick='togglePlayPause();'>Play</button>
</div>

JS:

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { initialiseMediaPlayer(); }, false);

    mediaPlayer.addEventListener('play', function() {
        changeButtonType(playPauseBtn, 'pause');
    }, false);
    mediaPlayer.addEventListener('pause', function() {
        changeButtonType(playPauseBtn, 'play');
    }, false);


    mediaPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function() { this.pause(); }, false); 
}

function togglePlayPause() {
    if (mediaPlayer.paused || mediaPlayer.ended) {
        changeButtonType(playPauseBtn, 'pause');
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
    else {
        changeButtonType(playPauseBtn, 'play');
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

function stopPlayer() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    mediaPlayer.currentTime = 0;
}


function replayMedia() {
    resetPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.play();
}

function resetPlayer() {
    progressBar.value = 0;
    mediaPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    changeButtonType(playPauseBtn, 'play');
}

$('.video').click(function(){this.paused?this.play():this.pause();});
```

I have a custom video player. But I am having troubles with my play/pause button. I know nothing about Javascript. I tried doing trial and error but nothing seems to work.

So here's my problem. I only need a play/pause button. When I play it, the icon changes to pause. Which is fine. And changes back to play button when the video has ended. But when I click on the pause button while the video is playing, it doesn't change back to play button, and worse, the video goes on repeat from the beginning.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend only telling the video player to play/pause on the click event and handle the switching of the icons based on the events fired by the player.

This way the controls will always reflect the state of the video without you having to set them every time.

```
<video id="myvideo">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div id='media-controls'>
<button id='play-pause-button' class='play' title='play' onclick='togglePlayPause();'>Play</button>
</div>

<script>


var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('myvideo');

mediaPlayer.addEventListener('playing', onPlay);
mediaPlayer.addEventListener('pause', onPause);

function onPlay(e) {
    document.getElementById('play-pause-button').innerHTML = 'Pause';
}
function onPause(e) {
    document.getElementById('play-pause-button').innerHTML = 'Play';
}

function togglePlayPause(){
    if(mediaPlayer.paused === true){
        mediaPlayer.play();
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

}

</script>
```